# Microsoft Account Authentication - AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

I have created a MVC web application and trying to use Microsoft Account authentication.

- I have created the App on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com
- After obtaining the App-ID and App-Secret I pasted both in my web.config
- In my StartupAuth.cs I have configured Microsoft authentication with this code snippet:

  ```
              var microsoftOptions = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions()
          {
              ClientId = Config.MSAppId,
              ClientSecret = Config.MSAppSecret,
          };
          app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(microsoftOptions);
  ```
- It is possible to authenticate with my Windows account
- In the account controller I am trying to create the account from data returned from the authentication provider. The snippet below only shows the important part.

  ```
  public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
  {
      var userName = string.Empty;
      var eMail = string.Empty;
      var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
      if (loginInfo == null)
      {
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
      }

      // Benutzer mit diesem externen Anmeldeanbieter anmelden, wenn der Benutzer bereits eine Anmeldung besitzt
      var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
  ```

  ...

await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() always returns null.

The configuration in the developer portal looks like this:

[image: Microsoft App configuration]

I have tried to add scopes for e-mail and basic information, but this seems to be deprecated and the authentication page shows an error.

In the debug console in Visual Studio I get the following error:

Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationMiddleware Error: 0 : Authentication failed
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Der Antwortstatuscode gibt keinen Erfolg an: 400 (Bad Request).
   bei System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   bei Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationHandler.d__4.MoveNext()

I have created a clean test project from scratch, to find out what the cause for the problem is. This is what I have found out:

- After the initial configuration of the authentication all Microsoft.Owin.Security.* components are on Version 3.0.1 and Microsoft Account authentication (not Windows Azure authentication - this is not part of the problem) works fine
- After updating Microsoft.Owin.Security.* to Version 3.1.0 some changes happen with Microsoft Account authentication. The logon experience changes. After clicking he login button, it redirects to the azure logon experience, unlike before, where I was redirected directly to the Microsoft Account logon experience and authentication stops working.
- After this I left all Microsoft.Owin.Security.* components on Version 3.1.0 and downgraded Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount back to 3.0.1. And voila, I got the "old" logon experience back, with the result, that authentication worked again.

The Problem must be in Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.

Does anyone know - except from using Version 3.0.1 - how to solve the issue or is this a problem for Microsoft support?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?